# How to check if iPhone's current location is within a specific region with mapkit

Tags: iphone, gps, mapkit

In my iOS app, a mapkit object displays the user's current location and zooms in on it.

I would like to put that code into an if statement so that it will only happen when the user is within a specified geographic region (a specific country, city etc).

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: I have the same issue, did you resolve it plz or could you give me a tutorial link ? thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Some Resources I found useful.

[CLLocationManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy)

[CLRegion Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLRegion)

[Core Location region monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845208/core-location-region-monitoring)