# Specific Country restriction Appstore

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, app-store, core-location

I have made application only visible to Germany, Now Apple informed to include Monitoring Shape-Based Regions for if the user move away after installing from Germany? How to monitor the region to restrict the application if exceed Germany area?

I have tried with following links

1) [Core Location region monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845208/core-location-region-monitoring)

2) [Apple: Location Awareness Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

My doubt is how to restrict application only available to Germany. Should I try with latitude, longitude. And how to monitor the regions/territory exception.

I uploaded it to the app store, but they reject with the following reason :

> 22.1: Apps must comply with all legal requirements in any location where they are made available to users. It is the developer's
>   obligation to understand and conform to all local laws.Please see
>   [Monitoring Shape-Based
>   Regions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/C%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bonceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)
>   for information on how to apply Geo restriction.

My doubt is how to restrict Geo location.

Comment: What kind of app is it? It would help finding a solution if it's a certain kind of app.

Comment: @Ermir Its a Game biting applcaition

Comment: Means you want to show your app in specific country ?

Comment: @bit-whacker Only in Germany

Comment: @ioseve have you found a solution? thanks

Answer (score 3):

By default, the app will be available in all countries the App Store currently supports, unless you specifically select individual countries/stores. You can choose individual countries.
log into `iTunesConnect` and click `Manage Your Apps.` Select your app and click the `Rights and Pricing` button. You can select the stores you want from this page. For More you can 
 [review the page 48](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf)

**Update**

As Updated 
Easiest way to solve this topic would probably is to decide which countries you want to make your app available in ? and as i have search something like review countries local laws to see if any thing is illegal related to the app. [And this relate to your Questions](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6813)

What if I make my app available on other countries than usa?

Comment: i did and uploaded in appstore, But they reject with the following reason `22.1: Apps must comply with all legal requirements in any location where they are made available to users. It is the developer's obligation to understand and conform to all local laws.Please see [Monitoring Shape-Based Regions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)  for information on how to apply geo restriction.`My doubt is how to restrict geo location

Answer (score 1):

If your application relies on location services to function properly, 
you should include the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` **key in the app’s Info.plist file**.

You can use this key to specify the location services that must be present in order to execute your application. The **App Store** uses the information in this key from preventing users from downloading apps to devices that do not contain the listed features.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

this link contains all the information you need.

Comment: but apple specifically said `Please see Monitoring Shape-Based Regions for information on how to apply geo restriction.` Should i want to specify the country in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities